# How to add a stored, generated column to a very large table?

Tags: postgresql

If I want to add a stored, generated column to a very large table (100M+ rows) it's going to take an unacceptably long time (in a locked state) because it must compute the new column for all rows before the transaction can complete.

There would hopefully be an alternative way to do this, perhaps like concurrent indexes or constraints where you can validate the column async. But, no, it doesn't seem like there is such an option, which is a bit of a shame.

Currently, my plan is to add the column using a function that is dedicated for the generation expression where the initial body of the function will be blank and therefore have minimal overhead to reduce the cost of applying it to all 100M+ rows. Then I can later on update the function body to the correct code and let the values update throughout the table naturally (I can stimulate this manually, async) and wait until the whole table is done. That's definitely not ideal.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(
    IN TEXT, IN TEXT
) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN

RETURN NULL;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN column_c TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( some_function(column_a, column_b) ) STORED;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(
    IN TEXT, IN TEXT
) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN

<the actual function code body>

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
;


<<then some async cursor process that updates all the column_c to their proper values without locking the whole table>>
```

Does anyone know of a better way?

[2024-01-21] Update:

I did a test on a duplicate of the table (same number of rows, limited number of columns) and found that the method I proposed above with the empty function took 7 minutes to execute; meanwhile the real-deal version (final function) took 14 minutes to execute. While the real-deal took far less time than I was fearing, the empty version is not meaningfully different. I will just have to schedule a maintenance period to do this and do the real-deal.

Still, I think there needs to be a better option for the future.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the column using a function"? Does the function execute an `alter table add column` statement?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. A generated column requires an expression. I am providing a function as that expression where the function is just blank. I'll update the description.

Comment: Consider creating a new table with a copy of the table structure using `LIKE` along with the new generated column. Create triggers to keep the new table in sync with inserts, updates, and deletes applied to the original table. Copy the contents of the original table to the new table in chunks. After the new table is fully synced with the original, the original table can be dropped and the new table renamed to the original table's name. Perform any other tasks that are necessary to ensure that the constraints and indexes from the original table are present on the renamed copy.

Comment: I would suggest to to add the new column without any default values or generation logic, allowing for a quick and non-disruptive operation. Then, you incrementally update this column in batches to spread the computation over time, significantly reducing the load and avoiding extensive locking of the table. Once all rows are updated, you can alter the column to be a stored, generated column with the actual computation logic.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com, as far as I am aware, PostgreSQL doesn't provide a mechanism to change a column to a generated column nor does is it possible to change a generated column's computation expression. If I'm mistaken, please provide the syntax for such changes.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com thats what I was wishing for in the body of the description, but no, I've been unable to figure that syntax out and its definitely not documented.

Comment: @JohnH That might work, but honestly it would be far far greater of a disruption and work than just locking the table. I'll provide a bit of an update in the description.

Comment: @AlexiTheodore, given the locked time mentioned in your update (which were lacking in the original post), the direct approach seams the best. The solution I proposed would have minimal disruption due to downtime, but would require additional development effort. The best solution would be for PostgreSQL to be enhanced to support virtual computed columns (as available in Oracle) instead of only stored.

Comment: Do what @JohnH suggests, but with one change: Instead of *dropping* the old table, *rename* it. This has the benefit of A) being instant - dropping table is slow due to logging and locks the table, and more importantly B) you can undo it if there's a problem - if the drop the data, it's gone! If there's a problem, rename it back in to existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to minimise locked time would be to:

1. Create the new column, `NULLABLE`
2. Create a trigger that fills the "generated" column

   - Probably `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` and the trigger function will do `NEW.column_c := some_function()` ... `return NEW` so that it fills the value into the "generated" column for new and updated rows.
3. Fill the rest of the rows asynchronously at your desired pace.
4. Once all the columns have a value in the "generated" column you can make the column `NOT NULL`

This results in practically the same behaviour as using a generated column.

Comment: also assuming that the "generated" column only depends on values from some columns in the table you can change the trigger to run ´BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF column_a, column_b´ where the generated column value depends on values of ´column_a´ and ´column_b´

Comment: thats not correct. Of course IMMUTABLE functions bodies can be changed, you just have to be a little careful about it because of caching. I've been doing it for years and never had an issue. But, yes, the trigger approach is also an option I considered.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I edited the answer, thanks for pointing it out!

Can you provide more insight into what advantages and disadvantages you see in this approach vs copying the whole table? To me copying the whole table seems like more work (dealing with FKs, synchronizing data) and more IO which might matter a lot in such a big table.

Comment: No prob. I did ultimately go with a trigger approach like you said. Very begrudgingly because its a LOT of extra code comparatively which probably shouldn't mean much and is probably the same overhead under the hood... but always bothers me. I absolutely agree that inherently if the issue is lock time because of a very large table (~300gb I think?) doing a table switchout with synchronization etc. is absurdly more work. I honestly would never have gone that approach. I just wanted a clever, cleaner way of making a generated column work.

Comment: Also... to give some more insight into the trigger approach, if you want something that really does the equivalent of a generated column, you're going to bump into another pg idiosyncraZy... which is that you cannot reference OLD and NEW in the trigger body when specifying `INSERT OR UPDATE` so that forces you to either do the OLD<>NEW check in the TRIGGER FUNCTION or use two triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, I think it could be useful for others!